How can embedded systems be elegantly compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit timestamp content printing?
This project github url: https://github.com/armink/FlashDB
#ifdef FDB_USING_TIMESTAMP_64BIT
    typedef int64_t fdb_time_t;
#else
    typedef int32_t fdb_time_t;
#endif /* FDB_USING_TIMESTAMP_64BIT */


static fdb_err_t tsl_append(fdb_tsdb_t db, fdb_blob_t blob, fdb_time_t *timestamp)
{
    fdb_err_t result = FDB_NO_ERR;
    fdb_time_t cur_time = timestamp == NULL ? db->get_time() : *timestamp;

    /* check the append length, MUST less than the db->max_len */
    if(blob->size > db->max_len)
    {
        FDB_INFO("Warning: append length (%" PRIdMAX ") is more than the db->max_len (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n", 
                (intmax_t)blob->size, (intmax_t)(db->max_len));
        return FDB_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    /* check the current timestamp, MUST more than the last save timestamp */
    if (cur_time <= db->last_time) {
        FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%" PRIdMAX ") is less than or equal to the last save timestamp (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
                (intmax_t )cur_time, (intmax_t )(db->last_time));
        return FDB_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    result = update_sec_status(db, &db->cur_sec, blob, cur_time);
    if (result != FDB_NO_ERR) {
        FDB_INFO("Error: update the sector status failed (%d)", result);
        return result;
    }
    /* write the TSL node */
    result = write_tsl(db, blob, cur_time);
    if (result != FDB_NO_ERR) {
        FDB_INFO("Error: write tsl failed (%d)", result);
        return result;
    }

    /* recalculate the current using sector info */
    db->cur_sec.end_idx = db->cur_sec.empty_idx;
    db->cur_sec.end_time = cur_time;
    db->cur_sec.empty_idx += LOG_IDX_DATA_SIZE;
    db->cur_sec.empty_data -= FDB_WG_ALIGN(blob->size);
    db->cur_sec.remain -= LOG_IDX_DATA_SIZE + FDB_WG_ALIGN(blob->size);
    db->last_time = cur_time;

    return result;
}


If FDB_USING_TIMESTAMP_64BIT is not defined and when CUR_TIME <= DB-> Last_time, it will increase the 32-bit type to 64-bit due to the conversion of compulsory types, resulting in inconsistent printing and expectations.
if (cur_time <= db->last_time) {
    FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%" PRIdMAX ") is less than or equal to the last save timestamp (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
            (intmax_t )cur_time, (intmax_t )(db->last_time));
    return FDB_WRITE_ERR;
}

question:

I found that there is no good way to be compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit printing. Except write an if else!.
The type is forced to be converted in this code. Where does the extra 32-bit content come from? Will there be other bugs caused by unexpected memory operations here?

I tested on the STM32 system and printed correct and incorrect examples at once:
static fdb_err_t tsl_append(fdb_tsdb_t db, fdb_blob_t blob, fdb_time_t *timestamp)
{
    fdb_err_t result = FDB_NO_ERR;
    fdb_time_t cur_time = timestamp == NULL ? db->get_time() : *timestamp;

    /* check the append length, MUST less than the db->max_len */
    if(blob->size > db->max_len)
    {
        FDB_INFO("Warning: (user PRIdMAX) append length (%" PRIdMAX ") is more than the db->max_len (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n", 
                (intmax_t)blob->size, (intmax_t)(db->max_len));

        FDB_INFO("Warning: (user PRId32) append length (%" PRId32 ") is more than the db->max_len (%" PRId32 "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n", 
                blob->size, (db->max_len));

        return FDB_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    /* check the current timestamp, MUST more than the last save timestamp */
    if (cur_time <= db->last_time) {
        FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%" PRIdMAX ") is less than or equal to the last save timestamp (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
                (intmax_t )cur_time, (intmax_t )(db->last_time));
        return FDB_WRITE_ERR;
    }

    result = update_sec_status(db, &db->cur_sec, blob, cur_time);
    if (result != FDB_NO_ERR) {
        FDB_INFO("Error: update the sector status failed (%d)", result);
        return result;
    }
    /* write the TSL node */
    result = write_tsl(db, blob, cur_time);
    if (result != FDB_NO_ERR) {
        FDB_INFO("Error: write tsl failed (%d)", result);
        return result;
    }

    /* recalculate the current using sector info */
    db->cur_sec.end_idx = db->cur_sec.empty_idx;
    db->cur_sec.end_time = cur_time;
    db->cur_sec.empty_idx += LOG_IDX_DATA_SIZE;
    db->cur_sec.empty_data -= FDB_WG_ALIGN(blob->size);
    db->cur_sec.remain -= LOG_IDX_DATA_SIZE + FDB_WG_ALIGN(blob->size);
    db->last_time = cur_time;

    return result;
}

1.Incorrect
FDB_INFO("Warning: (user PRIdMAX) append length (%" PRIdMAX ") is more than the db->max_len (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n", 
                (intmax_t)blob->size, (intmax_t)(db->max_len));

The corresponding printing information is as follows：
[FlashDB][tsl][LOG_TSDB][LOG_TSDB] Warning: (user PRIdMAX) append length (773094113460) is more than the db->max_len (549755813888). This tsl will be dropped.
2.correct
FDB_INFO("Warning: (user PRId32) append length (%" PRId32 ") is more than the db->max_len (%" PRId32 "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n", 
                blob->size, (db->max_len));

The corresponding printing information is as follows:
[FlashDB][tsl][LOG_TSDB][LOG_TSDB] Warning: (user PRId32) append length (180) is more than the db->max_len (128). This tsl will be dropped.

Can you give examples of correct and incorrect behaviour?

Hello, a supplement has been added

You are already using a C preprocessor conditional to define the timestamp type. That makes it simple to mimic the PRI* standard implemented by <inttypes.h>: Just define a format conversion string literal preprocessor macro alongside the type itself and then use that.
#ifdef FDB_USING_TIMESTAMP_64BIT
  typedef int64_t fdb_time_t;
# define PRIdFDB_TIME PRId64
#else
  typedef int32_t fdb_time_t;
# define PRIdFDB_TIME PRId32
#endif /* FDB_USING_TIMESTAMP_64BIT */

…

FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%" PRIdFDB_TIME ") is "
         "less than or equal to the last save timestamp "
         "(%" PRIdFDB_TIME "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
         cur_time, db->last_time);

This lets your code completely avoid guessing casts and format strings and just has the runtime do its job.
In the same preprocessor conditional, you can also define other things which depend on that type definition like e.g. the maximum size of a formatted string.

This I like....

OP's code  is fine.
FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%" PRIdMAX ") is less than or equal to the last save timestamp (%" PRIdMAX "). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
    (intmax_t )cur_time, (intmax_t )(db->last_time));`

Yet could be written simpler as
FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%jd) is less than or equal to the last save timestamp (%jd). This tsl will be dropped.\r\n",
    (intmax_t)cur_time, (intmax_t)db->last_time);


... it will increase the 32-bit type to 64-bit due to the conversion of compulsory types, resulting in inconsistent printing and expectations.

It does not result in inconsistent printing and expectations.

Where does the extra 32-bit content come from?

The 32 additional most significant bits comes from sign extending the 32-bit value.

Will there be other bugs caused by unexpected memory operations here?

No, yet (u)intmax_t might be going out of style in C2X.  Consider casting to long long (or int64_t) here as they are both at least 64-bit.
FDB_INFO("Warning: current timestamp (%lld) ... last save timestamp (%lld).\n",
    (long long)cur_time, (long long)db->last_time);


On, intmax_t, IMO, good riddance (we have enough trouble with types with variable size as it is). int64_t is semi-broken. On my linux x86 64 bit system, int64_t is: typedef long int int64_t and not typedef long long int64_t. Thus, it must be printed with %ld and not %lld. Even if that's universal, it seems counterintuitive to me [and you, apparently ;-)]. And, what happens on winX where long is 32 bits (even in 64 bit mode--the rationale for having size_t???). That's why I define my own 64 bit types with: typedef long long s64 [or equiv].

For printing int64_t, I use PRId64 (and neither "ld", "lld" and do not incur the issue you speak of.  For size_t, I use %zu to print.  Unclear what your size_t concern is.,

Re. size_t: Most systems are LP64 or ILP32, so sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *). See: https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html Except for winX where on 64 bit versions, long is [still] 32 bit due to backward compatibility with legacy code (e.g. int being 16 bits and long was used for 32 bits).  Without winX's choice we might not have needed a size_t [IMO, a necessary kludge] and could have used unsigned long (as the linux kernel does--because it knows it is using ILP32/LP64).

@CraigEstey Thanks for the elaboration.  Most systems today are among the billions per year embedded processors where even 16-bit int remain quite popular - many without an OS.  C is very popular there.  I have not found using size_t for object sizing and array indexing a complication.
